# How to open front custom camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

I need to open  camera on button click, my need is when i click on button then back camera get open and after clicking on capture photo, i need to open front camera as well.
Please help me out.

Picture Call back code:

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            File videoDirectory = new File(filepath,"Spooks");

            if (!videoDirectory.exists()) {
                videoDirectory.mkdirs();
            }

            try {
                Calendar _cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                long _timeStamp = _cal.getTimeInMillis();
                ////System.out.println( "Time stamp"+_timeStamp);
                String fileToSend = videoDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/" +"Image_"+ _timeStamp +".png";
                // Write to SD Card
                System.out.println("Write to SD Card");
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(fileToSend);
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

            }


            Bitmap realImage;
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 5;

            options.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared

            options.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future


            realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length,options);
            ExifInterface exif = null;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(path + c.getTime().getSeconds()
                        + ".jpg");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Log.d("EXIF value",
                        exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
                if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
                } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("8")) {
                    realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
                } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                    realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
                } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                    realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }


            camera.startPreview();
            //          camera.stopPreview();
            System.out.println("Back cam image saved");
            System.out.println("surfaceDestroyed on activity");

            /*_camera.stopPreview();
            _camera.release();*/

            //          finish();
            //          _camera.release();
            //          _camera.stopPreview();

            //need to open from camera
            _camera.release();
            _camera = null;



            if(_camera==null){

                _camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);

                _camera.startPreview();

                _camera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {
                    public void onError(int error, Camera mcamera) {

                        _camera.release();
                        _camera = Camera.open();
                        Log.d("Camera died", "error camera");

                    }
                });
            }
            if (_camera != null) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)

                setCameraDisplayOrientation(context,
                        CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT, _camera);
                preview.setCamera(_camera);

            }



        }
    };
```

Comment: You mean as soon as back camera takes picture you want to open front camera?

Comment: Instead of using intents to open the camera, have you considered creating a custom front + back camera instead? See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html . The section is Building a Camera App. Also see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html for the newer camera API

Comment: @Praveen yes, that exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: @Lunchbox i am using custom camera.

Comment: @Praveen i am using my own custom camera.

Comment: @Praveen Please have a look my edited code

Answer (score 1):

In your `OnPictureTakenCallback` open front camera.

```
 private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    public static final String TAG = "error";

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] mData, Camera camera) {
       /*
         Here do something with the taken picture, then stop
         the preview, release back camera and open front camera

      */
   }

}
```

Be careful while switching camera because you have to release current camera you are holding before taking on other.

EDIT:

`open()` method takes `int` argument as id of the camera. If you call `open` method without passing anything, it will open back camera. To open front camera you have to pass id of the front camera to `open` method.

```
Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
```

Comment: Praveen, i have pasted the code but still not working. Yeah there may be some release or start issue.

Comment: Praveen, i am still facing that issue. Can you please give the whole code of "onPictureTaken".

Comment: @ShoebAhmedSiddique Oh man.. As I said you should pass the id of the camera to open method.. Your this line _camera = Camera.open();  should be    _camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69369/discussion-between-shoeb-ahmed-siddique-and-praveen).